# Save copy of sent message on POP3 server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, pop3

Whenever I send messages from Outlook, the sent messages are not getting saved on the server (POP3).

Is there any way to save a copy of the sent messages in the server?

Comment: What e-mail provider are you using in conjunction with your Outlook account? Yahoo? Live?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not unless the server is configured to do so. POP is read-only; there is no way to write a message into a POP folder in the same manner as with IMAP.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt. In case of an IMAP server, how can I do that.?

Comment: ["Change where sent messages are saved when using an IMAP e-mail account"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-where-sent-e-mail-messages-are-saved-HA010164216.aspx#BM2)

Comment: "Not unless the server is configured to do so." How does someone configure an Exchange 2010 server to save sent items via POP3 on the server?